# Thunderbird 3 for Mac arbitrarily marks messages unread

Tags: mac, thunderbird

I just installed Thunderbird 3 on my Mac. Often when I click on an IMAP folder (other than the Inbox), Thunderbird will suddenly and arbitrarily mark unread numerous messages (from several to thousands) within the folder. I issue the "Mark Folder Read" command, which has the desired effect... until I click the folder again. The number of messages marked unread seems random. What could be the problem? This does not happen on my work computer, which runs Thunderbird 3 for Windows.

**Edit:** I have noticed recently that Thunderbird 3 for Windows has a tendency to mark messages unread as they are archived.

Comment: Do you use a gmail account? Because the difference between gmail tags and thunderbirrd folders could create inconsistency...

Comment: Nope, FastMail.

Comment: nothing strange about the permissions on the library folder? (I guess "library/application support/thunderbird").

tried deleting that folder and restarting from scratch?

is thunderbird doing something in background, like downloading more messages, while you use it?

Comment: I have noticed a lot of activity in the background. I will check these things when I get home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=540554) in Thunderbird. First try updating Thunderbird to a more later release.

Also I found [this blogpost](http://pol.spurious.biz/blog/archives/78-Annoying-Thunderbird-3-imap-bug-leading-to-readunread-flag-randomly-changing.html) after some searching. Maybe it'll work for you.

Comment: (Very good find!)

Comment: Nice sleuthing! I couldn't find anything on this.